# libgdx - Math for wall collision when adding velocity

Tags: java, collision-detection, libgdx, mathematics

I've created a game which spawns a random colored ball in the top or bottom of the screen and moves to random direction with this method.

```
private Vector2 position;
private Vector2 velocity;

private void move(float toX, float toY) {
    velocity.set(toX - position.x, toY - position.y);
    velocity.nor();

    velocity.x *= SPEED;
    velocity.y *= SPEED;
}
```

Now, I want to add 2 rectangles in the middle of the game and when the ball meets the rectangles or the wall (outside of the screen) it should calculate the new move position, but I don't know the math for it.

[image: Here's a picture which explains better what I want to have.]

Ball.java

```
public void update(float dt) {

    if(!isActivated) {
        if(position.y >= MainGame.HEIGHT) {
            move(position.x, position.y - anim.getFrame().getRegionHeight());
        }
        if(position.y == MainGame.HEIGHT - anim.getFrame().getRegionHeight()) {
            move(10, 10);
            isActivated = true;
        }
    } else {
        activeTimer += dt;

        if(position.y < 0) {
            // I need the calculation here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We have two cases, the first case being your ball is not colliding. Because of [Newtons First Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion#Newton.27s_first_law) your ball will have the originally random assigned velocity, \vec{v_{i}}. The second case is the one we are interested which is collision.

Assuming we are operating in 2 dimensions then we can treat walls and edges of boxes as line segments. Using our current model which only accounts for velocity, we can reflect the balls current vector \vec{v} over vector \vec{N_{l}} which is normal to the line segment the ball collides with. This results in the new velocity vector of the ball, \vec{v_{r}}.

This is easier to understand using an image such as the one below.

[image: angle_of_reflection]

A more in-depth discussion can be found at [Wolfram.com](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Reflection.html).